# UML Notation of HttpGet method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, uml, class-diagram

I'm working on a UML diagram of a Web API

[image: UML]

Where i have a HttpGet method:

```
// GET: api/Posts
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Post>>> GetPosts()
{
   return await _context.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToListAsync();
}
```

I'm not sure how to show that it is an async task with `ActionResult<IEnumerable<Post>`, and how the return should look like.

Second question: How would an association of a Model and a controller look like?

Comment: Please stay with a single question per thread and open a new one if you got more questions. You still may link both questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Preliminary remark**: It is not clear what `{virtual}` could mean in UML.  Prperty modifiers and constraints are syntactically expected at the end.  Is it possible that there is a stereotype defined in your UML profile to enrich standard UML with additional semantics?  In this case, it should be `«virtual»`.

**Asynchronous design**:  `ActionResult<IEnumerable<Post>>` could be modelled as any other type. You may simply consider it as a distinct class and use its name in `GetPosts()` signature. The asynchronous calls are not modelled in a class model, at least not if the call can be synchronous as well as asynchronous:  This detail is then shown in a sequence diagram.  However:

- You could think of using [active classes](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/activeclasses.html), for classes designed to always run in their own thread.  But asynchronous calls to a class do not seem sufficient to justify this.
- If some methods are designed for being always called asynchronously, you may consider modelling them as [receptions of signals](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/reception.html). Signal and receptions are less-known UML features that are meant especially for modelling asynchronous communication.  It's as simple as methods, but in a separate compartment, below the operation compartment, and each preeded with the keyword `«signal»`.

**Link between controller and model in your diagram:** The only model element in your diagram seems to be `Post`.  And the `PostsController` doesn't seem to keep any relation to `Posts`, except that it may use them in some calls.  You'd then show this relationship with a usage dependency (dotted arrow with the `«use»` keyword).  From an MVC point of view,  the controller is expected to know somehow the model to be able to send commands to it. It is possible that this relationship is indirect (i.e. `PostsController` is related to a `Controller` which knows a `Model` which knows `Post`) but this is purely speculative here; you could ask a distinct question focused on this problem, but with some more infos provided.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the great answer!

+ { virtual } Images : List<Image>
means:
public virtual List<Image> Images { get; set; }

Comment: If _virtual_ means _abstract_ you would just write the operation in italics without that virtual stuff.

Comment: @qwerty_so [*virtual*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) does not necessarily mean abstract. A virtual method can have an implementation that can be overriden by its specializations.

Comment: Ok, in that case a stereotype would be approriate, if... it depends. Putting languages specialities in UML does not suit me, except you bind yourself to that language. However, why should it go into the UML at that detail? Pointing out the abstractness would likely be enough.

Comment: @qwerty_so this is a very valid remark. Personally,  I’d not mention virtual for operations: this is a requirement to obtain a polymorphic behavior in some languages whereas in others it’s guaranteed by default. But here, I miss the parenthesis for making an operation and the operation compartment is empty. Apparently this is a C# feature called [virtual property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual). Like C# properties, this is a special beast that is not fully an attribute and not really an operation. So a stereotype could make sense